# using html.ActionLink but not html encoding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I wish to return the following output

```
<a href="#"><img src="/images/icons/tick.png" alt="" />More info</a>
```

If i do the following the content is html encoded.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("<img src='/images/icons/tick.png' />More info", "OrderRegion", "Campaign", new {id = Model.Campaign.Id}, null) %>
```

How can i disable the html encoding?

Comment: Your code does not match your output. Your output uses just `#` for URL whereas your code implies you want a URL to an Action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create an HtmlHelper to this

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static string MyActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var tagActionLink = htmlHelper.ActionLink("[replace]", actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes).ToHtmlString();
        return tagActionLink.Replace("[replace]", linkText);
    }
}
```

in .aspx:

```
<%= Html.MyActionLink("<img src='/images/icons/tick.png' />More info", "OrderRegion", "Campaign", new {id = 15}, null) %>
```

Comment: You should use a `TagBuilder`.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this, but using an Ajax.ActionLink?

Comment: If you're having trouble finding ActionLink method on the HtmlHelper class, it's an extension method and can be found by adding a `using System.Web.Mvc.Html;` statement.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are better off using `Url.Action` here, e.g.:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("OrderRegion", "Campaign", new {id = Model.Campaign.Id}) %>">
    <img src="/images/icons/tick.png" alt="" />More info
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are building an MvcHtmlString and want to include a helper-styled absolute path, you can use

```
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/")
```

and then append your link text, controller, and actions with fancy HTML/entites as string literals in the MvcHtmlString construction.