# passing html attributes to Html.Actionlink helper function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to know that how to pass html attributes to `@Html.ActionLink` helper function

i want to do like that

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#leftMenu" href="/Admin/UserManagment">
                    <i class="icon-user"></i>User Managment
                </a>
```

how to pass that italic html attribute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `@Url.Action()` as an alternative.

In this case your code would look like this:

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#leftMenu" 
    href="@Url.Action("UserManagment", "Admin")">
        <i class="icon-user"></i>User Managment
</a>
```

**Edit:**

Out of interest I did a bit of research and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4937466/849741). Which explains it isn't possible to use the `Html.ActionLink` for this purpose:

> The Html.ActionLink helper HTML encodes the link text which prevents
>   you from embedding HTML in the link text.

Comment: this is not what i asked

Comment: Sorry I updated my answer, I didn't read the last line, hopefully this answer is more helpfull.

Comment: It's really helpful for me :D

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to wrap html code inside the anchor tag using `@Html.ActionLink`

You can use `@Url.Action`

```
<a href="@Url.Action("UserManagment", "Admin")" ...>
    <i class="icon-user"></i>User Managment
</a>
```

Or create an extension method:

```
public static IHtmlString MyActionLink(this HtmlHelper helper,
                                            string value, 
                                            Dictionary<string, string> attributes,
                                            string innerHtml)
{
    var aBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
    foreach (var attr in attributes)
    {
        aBuilder.MergeAttribute(attr.Key, attr.Value);
    }
    aBuilder.InnerHtml += innerHtml + value;

    return new HtmlString(aBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

And use it in your views like this

```
@{
    var attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
          { "data-toggle", "collapse" },
          { "data-parent", "#leftMenu" },
          { "href", Url.Action("UserManagement", "Admin") }
        };
    var innerHtml = "<i class='icon-user'></i>";
}

@Html.MyActionLink("User Managment", attributes, innerHtml)
```