# How can I include markup as linktext in an anchor<a> in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-encode

Using Razor I have a page I want to put an anchor  whose linktext includes markup.
for example:

```
<a href="some url"> <div>Line1<div> </a>
```

I tried the following code:

```
@Html.ActionLink(@Html.Raw("<div>") + "Create New" + @Html.Raw("</div>"), "Create")
```

but it didn't work.

I know that this might look a bit odd. But is it possible to do that in MVC?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using HTML tags inside linkText of Html.ActionLink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936681/using-html-tags-inside-linktext-of-html-actionlink)

Comment: tnx Yogesh, so the answer is no, Sadly. I should use pretty pure html for that

Comment: Answer is no, if you want to use HTML.ActionLink. Look at my answer for possible alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. However, you can create a new HTML helper method for this. It should be pretty straight forward to do so. If not you can use URL.Action link.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")">
    <div> Create New </div>
</a>
```