# How to include i tag within html actionlink?

Tags: html, css, tags

SO I currently have following razor code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

How can i obtain something similar to the following HTML?

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Continue shopping <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936681/using-html-tags-inside-linktext-of-html-actionlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's not possible with current implementation of Razor HTML helpers.
HTML helpers are mostly used to generate very simple HTML. For complex ones, you will have to write HTML code yourself.
For your case, you will have to write HTML code your self instead of relying on helpers.

BTW

> @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })

This will output following HTML

```
<a href="/Home/Index" class="btn btn-default"></a>
```

& you are expecting `button` in output which is definitely possible.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
    Continue shopping <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
</button>
```

If you are expecting following output

```
<a href="/Home/Index" class="btn btn-default">
    Continue shopping <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
</a>
```

then you will have to write HTML code explicitly. You can use `Url.Action("Index", "Home")` helper to generate action method's path.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="btn btn-default">
    Continue shopping <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Url.Action at place of ActionLink

< a href="<%= Url.Action("Index", "Home") %>">< i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"><  /i>< /a>

Or

< a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">< i class="fa fa-shopping-cart">< /i>< /a>

please remove space after all breaks "<"..